# Restoring tempstore with another session ID

Tags: 8, users, sessions

I am building the functionality of sign in during payment checkout in Drupal 8, and I am storing all the values in Drupal 8's tempstore variable. I am capturing the session id for this anonymous user. After the user is signed in, his session ID changes, and I am not able to load the tempstore with the session ID of anonymous user. Is there a way to restore the private tempstore by another tempstore session ID?

So, the submit function of my custom sign in form looks something like this:

```
$anonymous_session_id = session_id();

$user = user_load_by_mail($form_state->getValue('username'));
$uid  = $user->get('uid')->value;
user_login_finalize($user);

$temp_store = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get($anonymous_session_id . '_com_reg');
```

When I do `$temp_store->get('some_value');` it does not give me any result since I am not able to restore the values. Can someone please help in this?

Comment: Generate cookie with random id and use keyvalue.expire storage,

Comment: Hey thanks, however I wanted to avoid using cookies. After much work around cookies, I finalized that I should stick with tempstore. I have posted my answer below, any suggestions are welcome. Thank you very much!

Comment: But there is no other way to identify the user. How you think sessions work?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue while trying to pass private.tempstore data through anonymous to authenticated user in Drupal 8.

The function

`user_login_finalize($user);`

Performs de migrate() method. This method migrates anonymous session to authenticated session, but only the Native Session Storage (Symfony).

Private.tempstore has to manually be migrated as Ekta tells.

If you can't or you d'ont know how to implement it, just store the data in native `$_SESSION['yourkey']`

The problem it's that native Session it's loaded every time a page it's called, and with Tempstore you have more control about this. For this reason it's not the better solutions!.

This could be a good issue for Drupal Core in a future, migrate the tempstore too when session login.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what I did. I was not able to restore the tempstore session key value pairs even when I had its id. I dumped the values of this session in an array, and destroyed this session. Once the user logs in, I populate the new tempstore session with all the values in this array. So, my code now looks something like this:

In custom Signin.php:

```
public function submitForm(array & $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    //session for a logged out user - this already has some values set
    $tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get(session_id());

    $temp_values = array();
    $temp_values = getFormValues();

    //optionally - write code to delete this session

    //login the user
    $user = user_load_by_mail($form_state->getValue('username'));
    $uid  = $user->get('uid')->value;
    user_login_finalize($user);

    //restore values in tempstore after login
    $temp_store = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get(session_id());
    restoreValues($temp_values); //restore the values from array to a new session
    $form_state->setRedirect('payment.payment_form');
    return;
}

function restoreValues($tempValues){
    //this is a tempstore session with new session id after user logs in
    $temp_store = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get(session_id());
    $sessionKeys = getSessionKeysForModule();
    foreach($sessionKeys as $index=>$key) {
        $temp_store->set($key, $tempValues[$key]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Custom module file:

```
//function to set all the session keys 
function getSessionKeysForModule() {
    return array('_company', '_country', '_address1', '_address2', '_city', '_state', '_postal_code', '_restore_for_anonymous');
}
```